# Distribution of the number of children needed so that at least both a girl and a boy are born

Tags: probability

A couple gives birth to a girl with probability $p$, a boy with probability $q=1-p$.
Let $N$ be the number of children needed so that at least both a girl and a boy are born.
What is the distribution of $N$?

For 
$$
P(N=k), k \ge 2,
$$
two children should be picked such that one is girl and one is boy, so
$$
P(N=k)={k \choose 2} pq.
$$
I feel this is not correct.

Comment: This is not correct.  The situation you want is for the first $k-1 \ge 1$ children to be one gender, and the $k$-th child to be the other.  This is just $P[N=k]=p^{k-1}q + q^{k-1}p$ for $k\ge 2$.  You should verify that $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} P[N=k]=1$.

Comment: And take care, $P(N=1)=P(N=0)=0$. Don't skip that the condition that it takes a minimum of two kids. @mjqxxxx

Comment: In particular, the formula $\binom k 2 pq$ is unbounded - as $k$ gets larger, so does the probability. In particular, you can get $$\binom k 2 pq>1$$

Comment: The probability that there are k girls is $p^k$ isn’t the possibility for any N that there is at least one boy and one girl equal to $1-(p^N+q^N)$??

Comment: What does P(N=k) mean?

Comment: $N$ is a random variable; it is the number of children at which you first have children of both genders.  $P[N=k]$ is the probability that the random variable has value $k$; i.e., it is the probability distribution of $N$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx I verified your expression $P(N=k)=p^{k-1}q+q^{k-1}p,k \ge 2$, and it sums to one. But, comparing to Khromonkey formula, $P(N=k)=1-p^k-q^k$, your formula seems to be missing some case. What am I missing?

Comment: Khromonkey's formula is $P[N\le k]$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx can you turn, as is, your two comment into an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the question a bit, let $N$ be a random variable equal to the number of children at which you *first* have children of both genders.  This takes on a particular value $k\ge 2$ when the first $k-1$ children are girls and $k$-th is a boy, or vice versa.  The distribution is therefore
$$
P[N=k]=p^{k-1}q+pq^{k-1}
$$
for $k\ge 2$.  The probability that you have children of both genders by the time you have $k$ children is
$$
P[N\le k]=\sum_{i=2}^{k}\left(p^{i-1}q+pq^{i-1}\right)=q\frac{p-p^k}{1-p}+p\frac{q-q^{k}}{1-q}=1-p^k-q^k,
$$
using the fact that $p+q=1$.  This approaches $1$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$, as it should, since you will eventually have both boys and girls, a.s. (that is, with probability $1$).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have $k>0$ children, the probability that all the babies are girls is  $p^k$. The probability that all the babies are boys is always $(1-p)^k$. Otherwise, you have both genders.

Therefore, the probability to have both genders with $k$ children is 
$$1-p^k-(1-p)^k$$

Specifically, for **any**  number of chilren, there's always a finite probability that they'll all be of the same gender, and therefore there's no such $N$.

Comment: (1) Take care when $k=0$. (2) What question are you answering? The current one asks for a "distribution" of $N$.  (I believe this question needs further clarification in order for the meaning of this request to be properly understood.)

Comment: if $k=0$ then clearly yuo don't have both genders...

Comment: Right, but your formula gives a "probability" of $-1$ in the case $k=0$, whereas it should be $0$.

Comment: OK. fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @yohBS I'm also puzzled by the wording of the question, and I can't explain how to define $N$. However, mjqxxxx pointed that your formula is $P(N \le k)$, which seems true as $1-p^k-q^k \to 1$ as $k\to \infty$.