# A couple want to have one girl and one boy. What is the expected number of children they will have?

Tags: probability, statistics, negative-binomial

> A couple want to have one girl and one boy. What is the expected number of children they will have?

I know that the answer is 3 and that the question relates to the Negative Binomial distribution but I'm not sure how to solve this. Can anyone explain?

Comment: They might have infinitely many children...  Are you sure that this is the correct question?  Or are you asking what is the *expected* number of children that they will have?  [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266150/distribution-of-the-number-of-children-needed-so-that-at-least-both-a-girl-and-a?rq=1)

Comment: Edited. I meant expected number of children

Comment: Do you mean at least one girl and at least one boy? If they go for one of each they know whether they have made it or not after two children.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe negative binomial is overkill here. It’s a geometric+1.

First they will have a child. And then they will keep having more children until they have one of the opposite sex.

So the expectation will be 1 plus the expectation of a geometric, which is 2. So in total 3

Comment: Nice simplification!